# How to synchronise duplicate RTP streaming with VLC?

Tags: networking, audio, sync, vlc-media-player, streaming

I would like to use VLC in order to stream an audio file from a server to several clients over an IP network. Both the server and the clients are running Linux. Here is my try for two clients:

*Server command*

```
cvlc test.mp3 --sout '#duplicate{dst=rtp{dst=10.0.0.2,port=5004,mux=ts},dst=rtp{dst=10.0.1.2,port=5004,mux=ts}}'
```

*Clients command*

```
cvlc rtp://@:5004
```

Although the music is correctly transmitted, the clients are not synchronised at all. There is a important time gap that makes it impossible to listen. Is this a normal behaviour ? I thought that a Real-time Transport Protocol could handle such problems. Did I miss something in the configuration ? Or should I take a look at another streaming protocol ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're not trying to do this over the Internet I suggest you use multicast instead of duplicated unicast streams. Basically, skip the duplication and use an multicast IP as destination and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not trying to stream over the Internet, so I'll take a look at multicast. However, the clients are not necessary on the same network interface, I hope it won't be a problem for multi-casting.

Comment: If they are on the same subnet it will work, if not you need to route it(e.g. with PIM) or leak it over to the other subnet/s(i.e. bridge the two L2 network).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Intenso suggested in the comments, the best way to achieve this it to use a multicast IP address.

*Server command*

```
cvlc test.mp3 --sout '#udp{dst=224.0.0.1,port=1234}'
```

*Client command*

```
cvlc udp://@224.0.0.1:1234
```

You might need to create network routes for the subnet 224.0.0.0/14, both on the server and on the client. Man "route" or "ip route". If your clients are on several subnets and you don't know where to route, take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/671278/how-to-duplicate-multicast-packets-on-several-interfaces/672999#672999).